# The ) is missing Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

This is my code, but i keep getting 'missing )' error. Please Help!

```
"If mid(FYM_01,3,4)=({@FY_as_Number})
    then 
      IF mid(FYM_01,1,2) = 01
        Then FYM_Link_A = PurchQty_10_Jan;"
```

Comment: On what line exactly is it being highlighted that a ) is missing?

Comment: If mid(FYM("Over here it shows that error")_01,3,4)=({@FY_as_Number})
    then 
      IF mid(FYM_01,1,2) = 01
        Then FYM_Link_A = PurchQty_10_Jan;

Answer (score 0):

See example for nested IF statements in Crystal Reports.  Try compare to your query and see if you are missing anything.

```
if {table.id} <> 1 then
(if {table.name} <> "Sample Answer A" then
  var1 := "Sample Data"
else
  var1 := "Sample Data 2"
else
var1 := "Sample Data 3";
```

Comment: The example was not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this ? is the FYM_01 a string ?

```
  "If mid('FYM_01',3,4)=({@FY_as_Number})
        then 
          IF mid(FYM_01,1,2) = 01
            Then FYM_Link_A = PurchQty_10_Jan;"
```